# Why this auto-update searcher is not working correctly? (Laravel + Vue)

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I want to create a simple searcher and I want to be auto responsive without using a button. I want if you write here, it search automatically with that characters.

I want to do the easiest way to create it, nothing complicated or install another items to do it.

I think the hard part is done, but for some reason it gives me the next error:

`GET http://webpage.test:8080/inscripcioneswebs/buscador?buscador=A 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Any idea?

##### `web.php`

```
Route::resource('inscripcioneswebs', InscripcionesWebController::class);

Route::get('inscripcioneswebs/buscador', 'InscripcionesWebController@buscador');
```

##### `InscripcionesWebController.php`

```
public function index()
    {
        $inscripcioneswebs = Inscripciones_Web::orderBy('INS_WEB_ID_WP', 'desc')->paginate(10);

        return view('inscripcioneswebs.inscripcioneswebs')->with('inscripcioneswebs', $inscripcioneswebs);
    }

public function buscador(Request $request)
    {
        $buscador = $request->buscador;

        $inscripcioneswebs = Inscripciones_Web::select('INS_WEB_ID')
                    ->where('INS_WEB_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $buscador . '%')
                    ->paginate(10)
                    ->get();

        return view('inscripcioneswebs.inscripcioneswebs')->with('inscripcioneswebs', $inscripcioneswebs);
    }
```

##### `incripcioneswebs.blade.php`

```
<div id="inscripcionweb">
    <div>
        <form action="{{ route('inscripcioneswebs.index') }}" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="buscador" id="buscador">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="resultados"></div>

    <table class="datatable">
        @foreach ($inscripcioneswebs as $inscripcionesweb)
            (The table DATA)
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
```

##### `inscripcionweb.js`

```
new Vue({
    el: '#inscripcionweb',

    mounted: function() {
        document.getElementById("buscador").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
            fetch(`/inscripcioneswebs/buscador?buscador=${document.getElementById("buscador").value}`, {
                method: 'get'
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(html => {
                document.getElementById("resultados").innerHTML += html
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: A 500 error is server error - since you control the server start by checking what the error is in the error log.

Comment: I think this error happens because the .js is not working well with the web.php or the controller, for that reason I'm asking about the code

Comment: You might think that, but the 500 error means there is a precise error in your error log telling you exactly what the problem is. If you need help go to /storage/logs/laravel.log and see what the problem is.

Comment: Humm, nice tip. The laravel.log say next info `Method App\Http\Controllers\InscripcionesWebController::show does not exist. {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\InscripcionesWebController::show does not exist. at C:\\laragon\\www\\atenea2022\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php:68)` ... so the function show is necesary in this problem? Humm

Comment: Okey @NicklasKevinFrank the problem was the show. I should use the code in `function buscador` in controller@show too. Thanks a lot m8! Please, put an answer in post with this solution in order to valorate positively and mark as the correct answer hehe.

Comment: You found the answer :) I just pointed you in the direction!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved thanks to the combination of @NicklasKevinFrank and @onovikov answers.

The 500 problem located in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` told me the problem was `Method App\Http\Controllers\InscripcionesWebController::show does not exist. {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\InscripcionesWebController::show does not exist. at C:\\laragon\\www\\atenea2022\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php:68)`

In `InscripcionesWebController.php` I created a `function show` and put the same code that `function buscador` and done!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem in InscripcionesWebController action buscador. You are need delete ->get() after ->paginate(10),  because paginate() return collection.

```
public function buscador(Request $request)
    {
        $buscador = $request->buscador;

        $inscripcioneswebs = Inscripciones_Web::select('INS_WEB_ID')
                    ->where('INS_WEB_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $buscador . '%')
                    ->paginate(10);

        return view('inscripcioneswebs.inscripcioneswebs')->with('inscripcioneswebs', $inscripcioneswebs);
    }
```

Comment: Humm nice tip. It appears the same 500 error but if his error dissapeared I think seriously this get() will be the next error, so thanks anyways!!